MS Build assembly reference not found in parent project
Here is the context:
I'm developing some plugins for a dotnet application, call it "ApplicationX".
In my solution I have 3 projects (all class libraries): PluginA, PluginB and PluginCommon.
PluginA and PluginB both depend on PluginCommon.
PluginA and PluginB are built to be installed as ApplicationX plugins, PluginCommon is not.
ApplicationX has a number of assemblies (*.dll) call them ApplicationX.Component__ that need to be referenced in order to use the API that ApplicationX exposes for plugins.
Now suppose that my project PluginCommon needs to reference ApplicationX.Component01, I add the corresponding assembly reference so this one project compiles fine, I actually don't care whether this assembly (ApplicationX.Component01) is included in the project output as it is not directly installed as a plugin.
PluginA and PluginB needs a reference to Component02 and Component03 respectively, so these also have their corresponding assembly references (works fine).
Problems:
(A) Both PluginA and PluginB outputs must not include any Component__ assembly as these are loaded by the ApplicationX itself.
(B) PluginA and PluginB also need to call into the Component01 API, as they reference PluginCommon I expected to transitively also include the Component01 reference, but it is not the case! Compilation fails wit messages like "The type or namespace name '...' does not exist in the namespace '...' (are you missing an assembly reference?)".
How should I setup the *.csproj files in the solution to solve the presented problems? regarding problem B, I would like to avoid repeating common Component__ references in final plugin projects (not just one in reality) to keep it DRY.
